# Android shared element return transition works from 11 recyclerview element and above

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I want two textviews from recyclerview to have a correctly transition when return. Now it works very strange I mean return transition for both textwievs starts from 11 element and then it is what I want, but before that just one textview (title) has a return transition. Why then return transition starts from 11 item and how to have this transition of course from first element on recyclerview list?

Here is my code and explanation.

I have a recyclerview which sets transitionname for two textviews dynamically:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Note noteItem = noteItemList.get(position);

    holder.noteTitleText.setText(noteItem.getNoteTitle());
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.noteTitleText, "title" + position);
    holder.noteDetailsText.setText(noteItem.getNoteDetails());
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.noteDetailsText, "details" + position);
   (...)
}
```

in this adapter I have ViewHolder in which on parent view I set onclick like this:

```
        rlNumberToGradient.setOnClickListener(view -> noteTitleDetailsOnClickAction());
```

where

```
private void noteTitleDetailsOnClickAction() {
        boolean edit = true;
        if (fragment instanceof FragmentMain) {
            list = db.getAllNotes();
            isOnMove = ((FragmentMain) fragment).isOnMove;
        } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentFav) {
            list = db.getFavNotes();
        } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentSearch) {
            list = db.getSearchNotes(((FragmentSearch) fragment).onChange());
        }

        if (!isOnMove) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean("edit", edit);
            bundle.putInt("position", list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            ((ActivityMain) fragment.requireActivity()).onPassValuesToFragmentShowNote(bundle, noteTitleText, noteDetailsText);
        }
        isOnMove = false;
    }
```

don't care about `isOnMove` variable, for this purpose lets assume its always true.

Once I click on this `rlNumberToGradient` view `onPassValuesToFragmentShowNote` method from main activity is called. It looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onPassValuesToFragmentShowNote(Bundle bundle, TextView tvTitle, TextView tvDetails) {
    bundle.putString("transition_name_title", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(tvTitle));
    bundle.putString("title", tvTitle.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("transition_name_details", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(tvDetails));
    bundle.putString("details", tvDetails.getText().toString());
    fragmentShowNote.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setReorderingAllowed(true);
    ft.addSharedElement(tvTitle, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(tvTitle));
    ft.addSharedElement(tvDetails, ViewCompat.getTransitionName(tvDetails));
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    ft.addToBackStack(fragmentShowNote.getClass().getSimpleName());
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentShowNote);
    ft.commit();
}
```

As we can see the fragment is showing up. Here is the key code here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext());
    setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
    setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_note, container, false);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        Bundle b = getArguments();
        position = b.getInt("position");
        transitionNameTitle = b.getString("transition_name_title");
        title = b.getString("title");
        transitionNameDetails = b.getString("transition_name_details");
        details = b.getString("details");
    }
    
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(toolbar, transitionNameTitle);
    ((ActivityMain) requireActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppBarLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout)).setExpanded(true);
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
    TextView tvNoteDescValue = view.findViewById(R.id.note_desc_value);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(tvNoteDescValue, transitionNameDetails);
    tvNoteDescValue.setText(details);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It turned out it was a uncompatibility. I tried to set transition on Toolbar and TextView. Once I get TextView from Toolbar with this method everything works fine:

```
    public static TextView getTextViewTitle(Toolbar toolbar){
    TextView textViewTitle = null;
    for(int i = 0; i<toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        if(view instanceof TextView) {
            textViewTitle = (TextView) view;
            break;
        }
    }
    return textViewTitle;
}
```